# Javascript true or false test won't output anything

Tags: javascript, html, output, getelementbyid

```js
function sub() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("imp").value);
  var yes = "Yup!"
  var no = "Nope..."
  if (imp == "true") {
    output(yes);
  } else if (imp == "false") {
    output(no)
  }
}
    
function output(x) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
body {
  background:green;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px #000000;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>TRUE OR FALSE</p>
<p>Polar bears have black skin.</p>
<input type="text" id="imp">
<button onclick="sub()">Submit</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `imp == "true"` isn't `imp` the HTMLInputElement? Why would that ever be "true"? Did you mean `num1`?

Comment: Oh my gosh... I just realised. Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: You should learn about how to use a debugger - those make finding such "simple" mistakes fast, and everyone makes these every now and then. PS: I don't know if that's all the problems of your code, it was just the first i got stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it seems you meant to check the value of `num1` and not `imp` (which doesn't exist in your code but is the name of the element you're getting the value from). I just changed the variable name to `userInput` to make it more clear that's what you're getting from the user.

Second, you're expecting either a "true" or "false" string from the user to make a check on, but you're trying to convert that to an integer. Remove the `parseInt()`. I added `toLowerCase()` on the end instead to prevent an error in the scenario the user uses any capitalization ('True', 'False', 'tRuE', 'fAlSe', etc).

Lastly, I'd recommend adding a final `else` statement to the end of your conditional check as a fallback for if the user does not enter 'true' or 'false' (always idiot-proof your UI to handle if the user entered anything unusual or unexpected).

```js
function sub() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("imp").value.toLowerCase();
  var yes = "Yup!";
  var no = "Nope...";
  var idk = "Invalid input";

  if (userInput == "true") {
    output(yes);
  } else if (userInput == "false") {
    output(no);
  } else {
    output(idk);
  }
}
    
function output(x) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
body {
  background:green;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px #000000;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>TRUE OR FALSE</p>
<p>Polar bears have black skin.</p>
<input type="text" id="imp">
<button onclick="sub()">Submit</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using some code from a calculator script and I guess I forgot to change  some stuff.